# App\\Events\\ChatEvent::__construct(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, string given

Tags: json, events, event-handling, laravel-8

This is my Event:

```
public $data = [];

public function __construct(array $data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

After I pass a value to the event:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
  {
     $chat = [
        "to_user_id" => $request->to_user_id,
        "from_user_id" => $request->from_user_id,
        "message" => $request->message,
        "unread_thread_count" => $request->unread_thread_count,
        "read_status" => $request->read_status,
    ];
    $data= json_encode($chat);

    event(new ChatEvent($data));
  }
```

I receive this error:

> App\Events\ChatEvent::__construct(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, string given

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue because your event `__construct()` method is expecting an array, but you're passing a string instead due to your use of `json_encode()` which will convert an array to a JSON string.

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or `false` on failure.

You can pass the correct value through to the event if you remove that string:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $chat = [
        "to_user_id" => $request->to_user_id,
        "from_user_id" => $request->from_user_id,
        "message" => $request->message,
        "unread_thread_count" => $request->unread_thread_count,
        "read_status" => $request->read_status,
    ];

    event(new ChatEvent($chat));
}
```

However, if your event is meant to receive a JSON string, then you should update the function parameters to set the correct data type:

```
public function __construct(string $data)
```